# When load WKWebview, its nil

Tags: ios, swift

I use Xcode 11.0 and Swift 5.1.
and I use WKWebview for load website, and There's no problem when I first loaded it.
but the second time to load a problem.

**filename: TabBarController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    var isSelected = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item)


        if isSelected == true && tabBarIndex == 0{
            let vc = ViewController()
            print("Go to amazon page")
            vc.handleReload()
        }
        else{
            if tabBarIndex == 0{
                isSelected = true
                print("home!")
            }
            else{
                isSelected = false
                print("setting!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**filename: ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url: URL = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}

//MARK: - function
extension ViewController: WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate{
     func handleReload() {
        let url: URL = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com")!
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

     func cacheReset() {
        let DataTypes = NSSet(array: [WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache, WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache])
        let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: DataTypes as! Set<String>, modifiedSince: date as Date){
            print("Cache Reset End")
        }

    }
}
```

The error occurs at `self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))` in  `func handleReload()`  
and Here's the error log:
`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`
I don't understand why WKWebview become nil :( 
Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create `ViewController` again as you have already added as a child to `TabBarController`. You can grab that instance as below and call the require method on that same instance instead of creating a new.

```
if isSelected == true && tabBarIndex == 0 {
    if let viewController = self.children.first(where: { $0 is ViewController }) as? ViewController {
        viewController.handleReload()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you gave me didn't work. with this error log:
Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'handleReload'

sry im a beginner, can you teach me another way to grab instance

Comment: @OreonHard Updated.

Comment: Thanks to you, I was able to solve it. Thanks a lot!